# Plot placement in GraphicsRow

Tags: plotting

I use the code below to produce a 3D plot next to a 2D plot, but cannot place the plots nicely. The output plot has a lot of empty space to the left of the 3D plot and very little empty space to the right. I played around with `Spacings`. In this way I could move the plots a bit closer together and the right plot further away from the right boundary of the image, but I cannot move the 3D plot more towards the left boundary of the image. How can I achieve a more equidistant arrangement (the output image should have a 4:3 aspect ratio)?

```
sur[p_List] := {p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[1]]^2 - p[[2]]^2};
surface = ParametricPlot3D[sur[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},PlotRange -> {{-0.7, 0.7}, {-0.7, 0.7}, {-1.5, 1.5}}];
GraphicsRow[{Show[surface, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500],Show[Plot[2*Sin[2*angle], {angle, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> (4/5),PlotRange -> {{-0.1, Pi + 0.1}, {-2.5, 2.5}}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try placing the graphs inside a `Graphics[ ]` statement, where you can size them at will. The commands that place graphics automatically, like the `GraphicsRow` you use here, do not allow as much customization.

Comment: @NicholasG You mean replacing GraphicsRow with Graphics? If I do that nothing is plotted anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the space between elements in a `GraphicsRow` using the option `Spacings`. In the present case, you could even use negative spacings, such as

```
sur[p_List] := {p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[1]]^2 - p[[2]]^2};
surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[sur[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.7, 0.7}, {-0.7, 0.7}, {-1.5, 1.5}}];

GraphicsRow[{
  Show[surface, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500], 
  Show[Plot[2*Sin[2*angle], {angle, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> (4/5), 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, Pi + 0.1}, {-2.5, 2.5}}]]},
 Spacings -> -100]
```

`Spacings` is not the most conventient solution as `AspectRatio`s are sometimes altered. Alternatively, you could use `Inset`, as in

```
Graphics[{
  Inset[surface, {-10, 0}], 
  Inset[Show[
    Plot[2*Sin[2*angle], {angle, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> (4/5), 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.1, Pi + 0.1}, {-2.5, 2.5}}]], {10, 0}]
  }]
```

The coordinate to `Inset` specifies where you want the sub-graph be placed. That should give you more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks! But all this seems to do is move the right plot more towards the center but the left remains where it is. I want to move the left plot more to the left as well.

Comment: @220284 I added a second solution with may offer what you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanks! I wasn't aware of inset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Inset` inside `Graphics` for precise placement, such as `Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {7, 5}], Inset[surface, Scaled[{.25, .5}], {.4, .5}, 5], Inset[linegraph, Scaled[{.65, .5}], {.5, 0}, 3]},(*Axes->False,*)AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]` (You might need to un-rem the `Axes` to place them as you like), which produces this:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help!